# JDBC SQLite ATTACH Query while using C3P0

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, c3p0

I recently implemented C3P0 in my database testing program (i'm using it to test different queries on our data in different DB formats... sqlite, mariadb, etc). The program was initially set up using a single sustained connection to do all queries. This worked fine with SQLite as I had to do an initial ATTACH on another table. When moving to C3P0 where it is necessary to open and close the connection on every query, how can one issue an ATTACH command and have it apply to subsequent queries? In my failure I did notice that the first query after the attach it seemed to apply.

Do I really need to interlace ATTACH test as TESTDB for EVERY query???

Running into a similar issue with setCatalog() for MariaDB. I get a "No Database selected" for every subsequent query after the first.

Comment: It is not necessary to open and close a connection per query, you need to open and close a connection per unit of work. And to better understand what you are doing, you really should show some code or an outline of what you are doing, because this sounds a bit like an XY problem. As I understand it, an `ATTACH` will add another database (not just a table!) to the current connection, which might indicate a problem in your design in the first place.

Comment: Hello again Mark. As referencing my previous post, my program is a producer/consumer with a queue in between, so in this sense a query is a unit of work. I have no way to sustain the connection without making it a global variable and for c3p0 i was told that I shouldnt do that. Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: I wonder why you need to attach different databases at all, and if that might be an indication that you need to use a connection pool per database instead. I don't understand why a producer consumer setup would necessitate multiple databases, so I'd like to have as much detail as possible. Also keep in mind that questions should be self-contained, but at minimum add a link to your earlier question if you think it provides context (although I don't think it is enough).

Comment: Sure. At this point this application is a test application to test various database query speeds with and without indexing. So i reference a separate database to get the source data to construct the test db, run the test, rinse and repeat. Its def more of a throw away prototype. Same format is used in another program for making a subset of data in a better table layout. (Source db is auto generated so we have little control over it)

Comment: So in the test program it is needed to make the database for testing and for the production program it is used to fetch missing data from the main db that was not contained within the sub database.

Comment: You could consider looking C3P0's connection customizers, see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connection_customizers Not sure if it is useful for your case: I have never had a need for this and I don't think I fully understand the details of your problem.

Comment: Try calling `Thread.sleep(1000);` immediately after you close your connection. That might give c3p0 and/or the JDBC driver time to finish releasing the old connection before you ask for another one, increasing the probability that you will get the same (wrapped) connection back again. (I just tinkered with it and it seemed to work for me, but my test app was single-threaded and was only asking for one connection at a time. However, without the `.sleep` I would get a different SQLite connection the second time around.)

Comment: Thanks Gord. That may work for the testing app but it is unlikely to work with an actual application that could need to ATTACH to another DB at any given time. :(. I just don't see a good method for doing that with C3P0 unfortunately.

Comment: If you mean "ATTACH to another *arbitrary* DB at any given time" then I would be inclined to agree. Perhaps you really do need a single persistent connection instead of repeatedly grabbing one from a pool of connections that may or may not be in the state you require.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking about for the testing program, using a persistent connection to do the setup (that's all it needs it for is to create the DB to be tested on). But for the production app, it's a Trending App. Its typical DB stores 24 hours of data for each point, but a client can request more and when that happens it must fetch missing data from the original source DB.

Comment: ... but if the "original source DB" will always be the same for each connection type (SQLite, MariaDB, ...) then you could either try the connection_customizers approach that @MarkRotteveel suggested, or you could create your own method to get the connection from the pool, check if the schema exists (for SQLite) or the current catalog is appropriate (for MariaDB) and then adjust as required before returning the connection object. One could argue that it sort of defeats the purpose of a connection pool, however.

Comment: This may actually work. Since I only do connections to a single source DB and use only one DB type per test, I can create a customizer for each DB type. I tried using it for SQLite so far and it seems to work. Now to try for Maria version.

Comment: @GordThompson This worked when using the ATTACH query for SQLite, but trying to apply conn.setCatalog() for Maria in the ConnectionCustomizer didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `setCatalog` may not be strictly necessary. If your code already does `SELECT ... FROM TESTDB.tablename ...` to handle the SQLite case then it could do the same thing on MariaDB without having to change the default catalog (database).

Comment: It says no catalog selected. Or no db selected, i forget which. Reason being is that i need to connect initially to the root (just address and port) because i first need to create the DB. That is why i cant directly use addr:port/db.

Comment: Well, if the catalog (database) may not exist then you can't call `setCatalog` unconditionally and expect it to work. You can either call `setCatalog` and catch the exception, or call `DatabaseMetaData#getCatalogs` first to see if it really does exist before trying to make it the default.

Comment: I do catch the exception at the moment. And it seems to still never grab the db after it has been created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I really need to interlace ATTACH test as TESTDB for EVERY query???

No. As @MarkRotteveel suggested in a comment to the question, we can use a c3p0 [connection customizer](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#connection_customizers) to tweak each connection as it is acquired for the pool. For example, if we create the class `OurSQLiteConnectionCustomizer` ...

```java
package com.example.sqlite_pooled;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.AbstractConnectionCustomizer;

public class OurSQLiteConnectionCustomizer extends AbstractConnectionCustomizer {

    public void onAcquire(Connection c, String pdsIdt) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement st = c.createStatement()) {
            st.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'C:/__tmp/SQLite/test.sqlite' AS test");
        }
    }

}
```

... and we tell our `ComboPooledDataSource` to use it ...

```java
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setConnectionCustomizerClassName("com.example.sqlite_pooled.OurSQLiteConnectionCustomizer");
```

... then whenever c3p0 acquires a new SQLite connection for the pool it will automatically perform the `ATTACH DATABASE` for us.

Comment: Yeah that worked. And as for the mariaDB connection i just referred to every DB reference by DB.Table.